# How to convert a jQuery form submission to Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've implemented a star rating system using the jQuery plugin "Star Rating". I use PHP to dynamically make the forms, and MySQL to upload the data to my database. I've tried converting to Ajax already, and the connection opens ([Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug)) but no data is passed.

Here's an example of the (dynamically generated) HTML form:

```
<form action="rater.php" method="post">
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="50830,1"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="50830,2"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="50830,3"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="50830,4"/>
    <input name="star1" type="radio" class="auto-submit-star star" value="50830,5"/>
</form>
```

Here's the relevant bits of `rater.php`:

```
$input = $_POST["star1"];
$pieces = explode(",", $input);
$recipe = $pieces[0];
$rating = $pieces[1];
//Go on to make a bunch of MySQL queries
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.auto-submit-star').rating({
    callback: function(value, link){
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
```

Every time I click a star, the MySQL tables update properly, but the entire page reloads. Nothing I have done to convert to Ajax has worked thus far-- what should I do?

Comment: In the future, when you get a solution you should keep your question up and mark the correct answer as accepted. This benefits the poster who took the time to help, it helps yourself with a solution, and helps anyone else in the future who visits the site and finds your question.

Answer (score 2):

What you have posted in your jQuery has nothing to do with AJAX. To get an AJAX POST request going, have a look at jQuery's `.ajax()` at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. That should sort things out.

An example for your case would be

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

(from jQuery site)

If you don't want any feedback, simply leave the `success:` field out. There is also an `:error` field to process errors and it works in much the same way as `:success` - use a function inside it to do stuff.

The rest of the call should be fairly self explanatory, as well as the documentation on the link I gave.

One final thing is to notice that there is no selector required for `.ajax()` calls - simply `$.ajax()` is fine.

Hope this helps,

James

### --------- EDIT ---------

For the data you want to send, try this piece of code. I have tested and it works great. I'm assuming you want the AJAX call run whenever a radio button with the class `.auto-submit-star` is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.auto-submit-star').click(function() {    // When the radio button is clicked...
        $.ajax({                                 // ... submit this AJAX call.
            type: "POST",                        // Method (POST or GET)
            url: "rater.php",                    // Path to your rater.php file
            data: "star1="+$(this).val(),        // The value of this radio button
            success: function(data) {            // Stuff to run on success
                 // Anything you want to happen on success.
                 // 'data' is the returned HTML from your PHP.
                 // If you don't want anything to happen, leave this blank.
               },
               error: function(data) {           // Stuff to run on error
                   // Any error handling you might want
               }
         })
     })
});
```

You can safely leave the `:success` and `:error` fields blank if you want no user feedback. If you *do* want feedback, let me know and I'll make some more edits :-)

I hope my example makes some sense. If it doesn't, again, let me know and I shall make amends :-)

James

Answer (score 2):

Try to use my [ALAJAX](http://www.alajax.com/) jQuery plugin. It's easy and simple. As simple as:

```
$('#form_ID or #div_ID').alajax();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also remove

> this.form.submit();

in your jQuery code to avoid the page submission in the callback function. It's better to just use the native Ajax function which [James demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364739/63550).